# Blink on ListView load Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to know how to avoid blink when a listview is loading it's data. I get the data from a Binding (names) and show them in a label. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IsVisible` Property.

For example, in your ViewModel, have a boolean, `IsBusy`.

When you load data from the server, you set the `IsBusy = true;`

After you load the data, you set the `IsBusy = false;`

In your Listview:

```
<ListView  IsVisible={Binding IsBusy}"/>
```